# Build with two entry points using 'react-vite'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vite

### crruent directory

react - vite

```
    dist
    src
        ㄴmain_external.js
        ㄴmain_internal.js
    index_external.html
    index_internal.html
    package.json
    vite.config.ts
```

---

`npm run build` -> `"build": "tsc && vite build"`

desired build result

```
dist
ㄴexternal
   ㄴ ...
   ㄴindex_external.html
ㄴinternal
   ㄴ ...
   ㄴindex_internal.html
src
ㄴmain_external.js
ㄴmain_internal.js
index_external.html
index_internal.html
package.json
vite.config.ts
```

> vite.config.ts

```
    export default defineConfig({
      plugins: [
      build: {
        rollupOptions: {
          input: {
            external: resolve(__dirname, 'index_external.html'),
            internal: resolve(__dirname, 'index_internal.html'),
          },
          output: [
            {
              dir: resolve(__dirname, 'dist', 'interal'),
            },
            {
              dir: resolve(__dirname, 'dist', 'external'),
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    });
```

I've tried the below, but what I want is for there to be one html per folder. What should I do?
We are developing with vite-based react typescript.